# access the controls of "Main Form", using the component script attached to Main Form

Tags: c#, winforms

[Sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38z15.png)
I want to access dataGrideView1 in component script that attached to Form1.

Answer (score 0):

You have such access through your component. So, in form1 source code you have to write component11.dataGridView1. Of course dataGridView1 has to be declared and initialized in Component1.cs

Comment: Thanks to reply. but doesn't work. I have the public variable in component script. I attach the component1 to Form1. Form1 has dataGridView1. I select the component1 go to property and assign the dataGridView1 to public variable. but to access the variable in component script i got the error :- object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I see. 
Problem is that you have you gridView as Form1 variable, but you try to access it from Component.

Then try something like this. In Component.cs create form1 type variable. Next in Form1 at the very end of Form1 constructor, type "component11.form1TypeVariable = this;"

And remember to make form1TypeVariable and dataGridView1 public.

In other functions you access gridView through Form1 type variable. Like this:
form1TypeVariable.dataGridView1.

Comment: Ok but if i attach this component to another form like Form2 then this does not work. How can i get the form name that attached this component script.

Comment: Ok. So if you want to create something more portable, you have to create interface. In this interface you have to include gridView from your Form1. Im not sure, but it is possible that you will have to use some namespaces, to make gridView class visible.

After that, your Form1 and any other will inherit interface. In Component.cs replace Form1 with interface.
If you will do something like this, you will be using something called polymorphism.

It is also possible, that you will have to configure your gridView by code, not by visual creator.

Comment: Your point of view is good. But its not best for me. Any other possibility?